# Android memory leak in app that uses custom views and ViewBinding on mParent in FrameLayout - LinearLayout

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary, android-viewbinding

I'm playing around with Android and building this calendar app and now I integrated Leak Canary into it and I'm trying to solve some view leaks. When in my Day View I switch from one day to another I just create a new DayViewFragment and replace my current one with the new one. When switching between these views, I always seem to get these weird memory leaks from Leak Canary but I am at a point where I don't really understand where they are coming from because I do follow all the recommendations from Google and all over SO.

One more thing would be that I keep my view inside a container called `_viewMvp` and it  uses a lot of nested custom views for all the elements on the screen and also using ViewBinding.

```
interface DayViewMvp {

    fun displayEvents(events: List<EventData>)

    fun showEventDetails(
        event: EventData?,
        onParticipantsClickListener: OnParticipantsClickListener,
        onNotesClickListener: OnNotesClickListener
    )

    fun onDestroy()
}
```

This is the Leaktrace:

```
====================================
HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
====================================
1 APPLICATION LEAKS
References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
161843 bytes retained by leaking objects
Signature: 56e49776fcd63a3cc7ee7a3825482429e7c535
┬───
│ GC Root: Input or output parameters in native code
│
├─ android.os.MessageQueue instance
│    Leaking: NO (MessageQueue#mQuitting is false)
│    HandlerThread: "main"
│    ↓ MessageQueue.mMessages
│                   ~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.os.Message instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 357.3 kB in 3593 objects
│    Message.what = 0
│    Message.when = 13029425 (16643 ms after heap dump)
│    Message.obj = null
│    Message.callback = instance @321482224 of android.view.View$ScrollabilityCache
│    ↓ Message.next
│              ~~~~
├─ android.os.Message instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 355.1 kB in 3545 objects
│    Message.what = 0
│    Message.when = 13029736 (16954 ms after heap dump)
│    Message.obj = null
│    Message.callback = instance @323119864 of android.view.View$ScrollabilityCache
│    ↓ Message.next
│              ~~~~
├─ android.os.Message instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 20.9 kB in 241 objects
│    Message.what = 0
│    Message.when = 13030175 (17393 ms after heap dump)
│    Message.obj = null
│    Message.callback = instance @323120024 of android.view.View$ScrollabilityCache
│    ↓ Message.callback
│              ~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.View$ScrollabilityCache instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 20.7 kB in 237 objects
│    ↓ View$ScrollabilityCache.host
│                              ~~~~
├─ android.widget.ScrollView instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 18.6 kB in 190 objects
│    View not part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mID = R.id.root
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of com.playground.calendar.ui.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ View.mParent
│           ~~~~~~~
├─ com.playground.calendar.ui.day.components.EventDetailsDayView instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 11.5 kB in 78 objects
│    View not part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mID = R.id.events_details_day_view
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of com.playground.calendar.ui.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ View.mParent
│           ~~~~~~~
├─ android.widget.LinearLayout instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 210.2 kB in 1689 objects
│    View not part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mID = R.id.day_view_events_layout
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    mContext instance of com.playground.calendar.ui.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
│    ↓ View.mParent
│           ~~~~~~~
╰→ android.widget.FrameLayout instance
     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.playground.calendar.ui.day.fragment.
     DayViewFragment received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback (references to its views should be cleared to prevent
     leaks))
     Retaining 161.8 kB in 1018 objects
     key = cfc4bc9c-425f-4fe9-abf3-d9e3f3ab944a
     watchDurationMillis = 8416
     retainedDurationMillis = 3409
     View not part of a window view hierarchy
     View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
     View.mID = R.id.day_view_main
     View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
     mContext instance of com.playground.calendar.ui.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
====================================
0 LIBRARY LEAKS
A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
====================================
0 UNREACHABLE OBJECTS
An unreachable object is still in memory but LeakCanary could not find a strong reference path
from GC roots.
====================================
METADATA
Please include this in bug reports and Stack Overflow questions.
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 30
Build.MANUFACTURER: unknown
LeakCanary version: 2.6
App process name: com.playground.calendar.audi
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=4058,misses=82278,hitRate=4%]
RandomAccess[bytes=4134619,reads=82278,travel=47802908326,range=30909359,size=39490755]
Heap dump reason: user request
Analysis duration: 10262 ms
Heap dump file path: /storage/emulated/13/Download/leakcanary-com.playground.calendar.
audi/2021-06-17_16-52-53_372.hprof
Heap dump timestamp: 1623948787233
Heap dump duration: 3202 ms
====================================
```

In my fragment, I do clear the reference when `onDestroyView()` is called

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        viewMvp.onDestroy()
        _viewMvp = null
        _binding = null
    }
```

In EventDetailsDayView I also keep a reference of this other local binding of the custom view so that I can later use it in other functions to set stuff up depending on other things in the parent

```
protected val binding by lazy {
        EventDetailsDayViewBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true
        )
    }
```

I don't understand how can `mParent` still be leaked? Can it be from my click listeners? Also how can `mContext` be an `Activity` level context? Is it causing the issue?
Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to understand what happend without code. May be your EventDetailsDayView register some callbacks  with attached to application lifecycle and this callbacks hold instance of EventDetailsDayView

Answer (score 1):

- The leaking FrameLayout is the fragment view of DayViewFragment and it's leaking since DayViewFragment#onDestroyView() has received the onDestroyView() callback
- The chain of references holding it goes through a series of View#parent fields, indicating that a child view of that FrameLayout is being held, and should have been released.
- There's a View$ScrollabilityCache instance that's been scheduled to run as a delayed message for 17 seconds from the heap dump time which happens roughly 5 seconds after the fragment view destroy => 17 + 5 = 23s => that was posted with a delay of at least 23s.
- That message scheduled in the future is what causes the leak. From reading the View.java source, it's only posted from one place ([sources](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java;l=18352;drc=95709ba69f9285cceb4515d86eff55793bc96eec): `View.awakenScrollBars()`:

```java
protected boolean awakenScrollBars(int startDelay, boolean invalidate) {
  // ...
  long fadeStartTime = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis() + 
  startDelay;
  mAttachInfo.mHandler.removeCallbacks(scrollCache);
  mAttachInfo.mHandler.postAtTime(scrollCache, fadeStartTime);
```

View.mScrollCache is private and as far as I can tell that post is not canceled when the view is detached. It should, so that's definitely a bug in the Android Framework (and you should file a ticket!). However, typically this bug doesn't create the leak for long, since the `startDelay` parameter is expected to be small. The default is 300 ms (400 ms for material), and 4 * 300 ms initially.

So I'd say here the leak is surfacing because something in your theming or code is increasing the duration of the delay before the scroll bars fade in so at least 23s (probably 30s?), by which time the view might be long gone but the posted message is still pending.